# ListBox cancel selectedValueChanged event

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a an issue I can't seem to find the answer to. OK, I have a dataset, dgv, and a listbox on a form. The dataset has a few tables and for some of the tables the primary key is selected  and set through the listbox selectedValueChanged event. The user clicks a name in the listbox and the item selectedValue is assigned to the item variable.

```
item = Me.ListBoxItem.SelectedValue
Me.itemID = index
```

I also have a boolean dsIsEditing which is set to false if the changes in the dgv haven't been submitted to the database. What I'm looking to do is prevent the user from selecting another item in the list if dsIsEditing = true.

I know there's a ListBox validating event with a cancelEventArgs argument but I can't figure out how to implement it. The closest I've gotten is implementing the code below from the ListBoxItem selectedValueChanged event:

```
    If dsIsEditing = True Then
        Dim result As MsgBoxResult
        Dim clearMsg As String
        clearMsg = "You have unsave changes. Are you sure you " & _
                   "want to proceede? Any unsave changes will be lost."

        result = MessageBox.Show(clearMsg, "Switching Order Selection", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2)
        If result = MsgBoxResult.No Then
            RemoveHandler ListBoxItem.SelectedValueChanged, AddressOfListBoxItem_SelectedValueChanged
            Me.ListBoxItem.SelectedValue = Me.itemID
            AddHandler ListBoxItem.SelectedValueChanged, AddressOf ListBoxItem_SelectedValueChanged
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
```

The code does what I want it to, but let's say the current item is item H, if I click on item B it will show as selected in the ListBox, and then if I choose not to continue it'll revert back to item H. My headache here :) is finding the correct code so that item B doesn't ever show as selected in the ListBox if No is selected from the messageBox. Thanks in advance for your responce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When designing user interface interactions, I have found that it is a much better user experience to prevent the user from doing something rather than telling them it is not ok and then trying to undo what they have done.

In your situation, what I would do is as soon as the dsIsEditing flag is set to true, disable the ListBox and then enable a Cancel (or Undo) Editing button.

The Cancel Editing button would ask the user the same question you have above and perform any actions necessary.

When the changes are successfully saved, re-enable the listbox and disable the Cancel Editing button.

If for some reason this won't work, you could:

1. Look for a third-party control that supports something like a SelectedValueChanging event that would allow you to cancel the operation before the value is changed.
2. Subclass the ListBox control and attempt to implement this functionality on your own by overriding the OnSelectedValueChanged method, although I am not 100% convinced that this will solve your particular issue. [Here is an example](http://diegworld.blogspot.com/2010/12/combobox-selectedvaluechanging-event.html) of this in action for ComboBox; the implementation for ListBox should be nearly identical.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I guess I was on the right track according to your suggestion to disable the ListBox control. I also have a DateTimePicker control that I set to disabled once dsIsEditing=True. I should have thought to do the same with the ListBox. Also thank you for the link to the code sample. Take care.